# Creating tests of datatypes in SML

Tags: sml

I would like to create unit tests for a program I wrote in SML.

Consider a function

```
val foo = fn : int -> int seq
```

For `foo 5` it will return: `val it = foo (5,fn) : int seq`. (`seq` is some datatype).

It doesn't really matter what it does, I'm just interested in creating tests which checks the left item of the tuple.

I tried:

```
val test = ((foo 5) = (seq (5,_)));

val test = ((foo 5) = (seq (5,fn)));
```

But they didn't work. Is there a one line test I can write in order to verify that the left tuple contains `5`?

Comment: What was the error? Can you give a minimal reproducible code sample that we can use to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a pattern-matching let-binding;

```
val test = let val seq (x,_) = foo 5 in x = 5 end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to test an abstract interface that accesses this data type. In case of `'a seq` (I assume this is a lazy stream of `'a`), you could have a `take` function and test this. For example,

```
datatype 'a seq = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq)

fun from n = Cons (n, fn () => from (n+1))

fun take 0 _ = []
  | take n (Cons (x, f)) = x :: take (n-1) (f ())
```

And a test of `take` might look like:

```
val nats = from 0

val test_take_1 = take 0 nats = []
val test_take_2 = take 1 nats = [0]
val test_take_3 = take 3 nats = [0,1,2]
val test_take_4 = ( take ~1 nats ; false )
                  handle Out_of_memory => true
                       | _             => false
```

Here I'm testing that `take` fails as expected when `n` is negative.

If it either doesn't fail, or it fails with some other exception than `Out_of_memory`, the test fails.

---

So:

1. Define your data type,
2. Define the abstract interface that accesses it,
3. Test that abstract interface.